# switch recognized item in grxml file

Tags: xml, grammar, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I have created a grammar (in grxml format) to recognize the OMV literal (with hu-hu language settings)

This is the problematic part:

```
<item>oemfau</item>
```

nuance recognize it, and print 'oemfau', but i want that nuance say, the word is not oemfau, but OMV. How can i switch the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your grammar uses `tag-format="swi-semantics/1.0`, you can use ECMAScript in a `<tag>` element like this:

```
<item>
   oemfau
   <tag>out.slot = &quot;OMV&quot;</tag>
</item>
```

Simply replace "slot" with whatever NL slot you'd like to use in your application.